# How to use transform orientation in several scenes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I've created a custom transform orientation based on object Z in scene A. I also created a scene B where where I also need this orientation but object Z has no instance. I know, that I can link object Z to scene B, create a new custom transform orientation and delete object Z from scene B again. But this doesn't seem to be very comfortable to me.
Is there a way to link transform orientations to several scenes?

Comment: The only solution I know would be to plan ahead and create full copies of all the scenes that will need to share a custom transform orientation, before even creating any objects for those scenes. Then the needed transform orientations will continue to be available in all such scenes, even after creating different objects in each scene. Not a complete solution, but by doing it this way, you never have to delete any objects later on, at least. I don't know any way to transfer only the transform orientation from scene to scene. There doesn't appear to be a node associated with them.